# MQTT is it possible to get back a token number after I publish

Tags: java, jms, publish-subscribe, mqtt

I am using MQTT for a POC , What I need is a reference ID for the messages I have published to the topic. There is MqttDeliveryToken , but it do not give a token number as its name.

It gives `isdeliveryComplete and getMessage` , not a reference number of any sort.

basically I would need is a reference number.Like for eg: when we raise a ticket in ticketing systems,we get a ticket number for our future reference. Something of that sort.

Comment: What are you going to use the number for? If your application needs a unique id for each message then it is your responsibility to add this to the message body

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the Eclipse Paho library as MQTT client library. It is not clear what you want kind of number you want. If you want to use the MQTT message id (which is only available for Quality of Service 1 and 2 btw) as a reference number for applications like your ticketing system, this is probably a very bad idea because they are not globally unique and the implementation is client specific.

It seems like you want to send a reference number in the payload of the MQTT message. Just add it to the PUBLISH message when publishing and extract it on your subscriber.

If your questions aims how to use Paho, there are some Github Repositories which show how to use it. Here is an old one of me (with an older Paho version. Not 100% API compatible) https://github.com/dobermai/paho-publish-subscribe

Comment: the message id is sequential and not unique. In activeMQ , I used to get a reference number. So in MQTT there is no reference of that sort. And I will have to generate a unique number,maybe an epoch timestamp. ?

Comment: @Dominik, in different context, As per you code at https://github.com/dobermai/android-mqtt-push, mqtt connection and callback is simple and working.But Poho recommend to used its service jar (org.eclipse.paho.android.service) alongwith mqttv3 jar as https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/.I saw the service jar at github and it look complex. Actually I want to use Mqtt connection for an application which already has a service with multiple and complex methods. I need your help to understand "should I go with simple method mentioned in your code or use another service if need qos = 0 only?"

Comment: @ajay The repository you mentioned is a simple proof-of-concept and is not be meant to be used for production purposes. It's very easy to wrap the simple method in a service. I'd go with the recommendation and use the Paho service, though